# What are off-hours in SO terms?

Tags: discussion, moderator-election

In [the mod election](https://stackoverflow.com/election), multiple candidates have said that they are usually on at off hours. When is that, exactly? Is it a good thing? Do we need more mods when there are less users online, or is their time more valuable just after new posts come in?

Comment: _when there are less users online_ not sure how you came to that conclusion..users are from all sorts of timezones

Comment: @suraj isn't that the definition of off-hours?

Comment: Most of the time the community can handle things by itself (casting votes, etc) so I don't think it should we should be Babysitted ;) They are almost always around BTW, so it's not like SO isn't monitored for long periods of time

Comment: @FilipHaglund I meant what is off hours to a person may not be for a bunch of other users

Comment: @suraj that was my point; there's probably a peak in US/EU timezones, but I have SO-specific data to back this up, and I don't know if it's a good/bad thing for a mod to be available in those timezones or not.

Comment: This may refer to *their* off-time, meaning when they are not otherwise engaged. or it may refer to the point of the day where there are the least amount of moderators online. In which case, this could be perceived as a good thing, because it is good to have as many exception handlers active at a given time as necessary to handle all exceptions.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Honestly, I've never put much stock into timezones for Stack Overflow moderator candidates. Here's why:

[image]

We've got flags in that queue reaching back to June 13th. Almost none of them are urgent - and if they were, you're unlikely to see them within an hour or two anyway. Spam flags are the exception, they're surfaced pretty well and are handled quickly already.

I'm in the US, and I often find I'm handling things that happened 3+ hours ago. Occasionally I'll find a 'hot' comment debate to extinguish, but that's rare.

Where it starts to matter is chat - but remember, chat is the Third Place. Issues there are *comparatively* rare when you think of the volume on the main site versus chat. It's not a priority, and shouldn't be.

I'm not handling as many flags as I used to, but my view is simple: There are plenty of flags in *every* timezone.

Comment: It used to be *a little bit* important to try and spread mods out over several time zones, but yeah, this hasn't been a big issue for quite a while. It would be better to have a few active mods lumped into one time zone than to have inactive mods spread out.